# Iphone SQlite - Populate Table from Text Field

Tags: objective-c, iphone, sqlite

I am trying to prepopulate my SQlite Table from a Text File - alltough it is compiling fine, no rows will be inserted:

```
NSLog(@"Insert Table for English");


    char *errorMsg;

    NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath ] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"english.sql"];

    NSLog(@"DefaultPath: %@", defaultDBPath);

    NSString *sql = [[[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:defaultDBPath  
                                           encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding 
                                              error:NULL] autorelease];

    if (sqlite3_exec(database,[sql UTF8String],NULL,NULL, &errorMsg) != SQLITE_OK) {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error loading update file: %s", errorMsg);
    }

    NSLog(@"I should have written something");
```

This is how my text file looks like:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO PARTNER(branche) VALUES('Choose music for the Ceremony');
COMMIT;
```

I create the Database here:

```
-(void)createDatabase {

NSUserDefaults *userSETTINGS = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSLog(@"HUHU - schau ma mal: Database = %d", [userSETTINGS integerForKey:@"Database"]);


if ([userSETTINGS integerForKey:@"Database"] == 0) {


    if (sqlite3_open([[self dataFilePath] UTF8String], &database) != SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_close(database);
        NSAssert(0, @"Failed to open database");
    }

    char *errorMsg;
    //sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    NSString *createSQL = @"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PARTNER (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, branche TEXT, company TEXT, name TEXT, phone TEXT, email TEXT, price INT, notes TEXT, done TEXT);";
    if (sqlite3_exec(database, [createSQL UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &errorMsg) != SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_close(database);
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error createing table: %s", errorMsg);
    }

    NSUserDefaults *userSETTINGS = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userSETTINGS setInteger:1 forKey:@"Database"];

    NSLog(@"HUHU - schau ma mal: Database = %d", [userSETTINGS integerForKey:@"Database"]);

[self fillDatabase];

} else {

    NSLog(@"Database wurde schon angelegt");
    [self readDatabase];

}
```

}

The Log File tells my, that defaultDBPath is:

> DefaultPath: /Users/sl/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications/0BE2EDC6-F070-43BE-9666-310257B495B9/WeddingPlanner.app/english.sql

What am I missing? The DB is correct, the Path is OK but nothing will be written...

Thanks for your answers, help, advice... :-)

BR,

Stefan

---

Thanks again for your continous help...

I have changed as follows:

```
if (sqlite3_open_v2([[self dataFilePath] UTF8String], &database, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, nil) != SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_close(database);
        NSAssert(0, @"Failed to open database");
    }

    NSLog(@"Insert Table for English");


    char *errorMsg;

    NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath ] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"e.sqlite"];

    NSLog(@"DefaultPath: %@", defaultDBPath);

    NSString *sql = [[[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:defaultDBPath  
                                           encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding 
                                              error:NULL] autorelease];

    if (sqlite3_exec(database,[sql UTF8String],NULL,NULL, &errorMsg) != SQLITE_OK) {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error loading update file: %s", errorMsg);
    }

    NSLog(@"Hier hätte ich schreiben sollen");
```

My Log looks like:

> 2010-02-21 20:37:41.666 WeddingPlanner[61189:207] Nil on start
>   2010-02-21 20:37:41.668 WeddingPlanner[61189:207] HUHU - schau ma mal:
>   Database = 1 2010-02-21 20:37:41.669 WeddingPlanner[61189:207]
>   Database wurde schon angelegt 2010-02-21 20:37:41.670
>   WeddingPlanner[61189:207] Abfrage: SELECT SUM(price) FROM PARTNER
>   2010-02-21 20:37:41.671 WeddingPlanner[61189:207] Nil on start
>   2010-02-21 20:37:41.672 WeddingPlanner[61189:207] Die gesetzte
>   Sprache: (null) 2010-02-21 20:37:41.682 WeddingPlanner[61189:207]
>   Abfrage: SELECT SUM(price) FROM PARTNER 2010-02-21 20:37:41.683
>   WeddingPlanner[61189:207] Nil on start 2010-02-21 20:37:41.685
>   WeddingPlanner[61189:207] HUHU - schau ma mal: (null) 2010-02-21
>   20:37:41.685 WeddingPlanner[61189:207] calculateDateDifference
>   2010-02-21 20:37:41.691 WeddingPlanner[61189:207] Das Datum DAY =
>   -3338 wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003 2010-02-21 20:37:56.597 WeddingPlanner[61189:207] English 2010-02-21 20:37:56.599
>   WeddingPlanner[61189:207] Die gespeicherte Sprache: EN 2010-02-21
>   20:37:56.600 WeddingPlanner[61189:207] Insert Table for English
>   2010-02-21 20:37:56.602 WeddingPlanner[61189:207] DefaultPath:
>   /Users/sl/Library/Application Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/User/Applications/D79C5BB0-B4E1-4AD7-8B9B-E4493D82F64D/WeddingPlanner.app/e.sqlite

So everthing looks fine - DB will be created, DB can be opened (because there is no failure issue), I am able to insert (view GUI) data into the table "partner", but I am not able to insert data via file...

Answer (score 0):

[The correct syntax for committing transaction](http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#commit-stmt) is

```
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Comment: HI Kenny, 

thanks a lot for your feedback, but it looks like, that I have 2 Errors - the first one should be solved (COMMIT TRANSACTION) but there is another one, because the DB will not populated.

BR,

Stefan

Comment: @Stefan: What is `[self dataFilePath];`?

Comment: Hi Kenny,


-(NSString *)dataFilePath {
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
 return [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:kFilename];
 
}

The DB will be created - this is working - even read is working, but populating is failing! Does the sqlite file should be a special file? I have simply created it in Xcode as I am creating the DB in the file and I just want to have the statements in the file..Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: @Stefan: That's fine. Try to open with `sqlite3_open_v2` and supply the `SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE|SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE` flags (though this is the default). And try to run each line one by one. Did the console return any error messages?